# ANN : I cannot train my custom loss function using gradient descent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss

I am trying to train my multi-input (100 features) multi-output (3 outputs) model using **gradient descent but the loss function does not tends towards 0.**

**The loss function is on the following picture :** [loss(y_true, y_pred)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u4k2.png). This loss function rewards the classification (if you get the right sign) of data with large value.

Here is the code of my loss function :

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred) : 
    d = tf.raw_ops.Sum(input = tf.raw_ops.Abs(x= y_true, name = None), axis = -1, keep_dims = False, name = None)
    n = tf.raw_ops.Sum(input = tf.raw_ops.Sign(x = y_true*y_pred, name = None)*tf.raw_ops.Abs(x = y_true, name = None), axis = -1, keep_dims = False, name = None)
    return 1-n/d
```

I am using `tf.raw_ops` because it seems that `sign()` and `abs()` are **differentiable** (weird..) : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops .

I implemented this loss function to train the following model (ANN with 3 layers with 50 nodes each) :

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

classifier = Sequential()

#Layers 
classifier.add(Dense(units = 50, input_shape = (100, ), activation = "relu"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 50, activation = "relu"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 50, activation = "relu"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=3, activation = 'tanh'))

# Compilation
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = my_loss_fn) 

#Training
nb_epochs = 300
history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = nb_epochs, batch_size = 128, verbose = True)
```

The loss does not tend towards zero and varies between 0.99 and 1.05.

I am using **tensorflow 1.14.0**.

Can you help me with this problem ?

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Your output layer has `relu` activation, you may want to change that first.

Comment: I also tried using 'tanh' for the output layer since I want negatives and positives values but the absolute value does not matter and I get the same results